# Develop and Debug an Eclipse web app in ONE project

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jsp, tomcat

Does anybody know how to use the SAME Eclipse project for development AND deployment AND debugging?
My current worksteps are:
- create a dynamic web app project in Eclipse
- create a WAR file
- upload it into tomcat
- then debug it on tomcat
This way I cannot develop the project, only debug.
I tried to create a dynamic web app project directly in tomcat's webapps folder, but Eclipse always creates another structure than tomcats wants to have (e.g. no Webcontent folder).
Is there any possibility to keep develoment AND debugging together?
I do not want to start tomcat within Eclipse, but to launch the running tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse includes a facility to publish, run and debug dynamic web projects on a variety of application servers, including Tomcat.

Do not place your project in Tomcat's webapps folder. Place it where it makes sense for you to keep source code.

Use "Servers" view to define a Tomcat server and associate your project with it. From the Servers view, you will be able to start/stop Tomcat and publish your project. If you do not see Servers view in your current perspective, find it under Window -> Show View -> Other.

You can also jump straight to debugging by right-clicking on an artifact that you want to run (such as a jsp file) and using Run As -> Run On Server or Debug As -> Debug On Server.

Comment: You have stated the default method. But I want to lauch the running tomcat, not to start it within Eclipse. Lauching the server works, but not the hot deploy of sources, since I have no possibility to export correctly. Maybe this is not possible?

Comment: You don't have to start Tomcat within Eclipse. It will work just as well with a running instance of Tomcat. Once you define a server, double click on it to access various settings on how Eclipse interacts with the server. One of the settings is automatic publish. If you enable it, any project changes will be visible pretty much immediately in the published webapp.